# Creating A Responsive Menu with HTML, CSS & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a responsive menu following this guide http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/responsive-menu/ everything's working fine  when the width is less than 980px, the menu (the three dash) is showing but not opening.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone tell me?

It's not working on my website:

[image: see this]

Here's my HTML Code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url("img-bg-mobile.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: open sans;
}

.toggle-nav {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    nav {
    height: auto;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:17%;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 2%;
}

nav ul li a{
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: open sans;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none;

}

nav ul li ul a {
    color: #ff3c1f;
}

nav ul li:hover ul
{
  display:block;
  height:auto;
  width: 110px;
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

.menu {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menu ul {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:120%;
    left:0px;
    padding:10px 18px;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#303030;
}

.menu ul.active {
    display:none;
}

.menu ul:after {
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0%;
        left:22px;
        content:'';
        transform:translate(0%, -100%);
        border-left:7px solid transparent;
        border-right:7px solid transparent;
        border-bottom:7px solid #303030;
    }
.menu li {
        margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;
        float:none;
        display:block;
    }

.menu a {
        display:block;
    }
 
.toggle-nav {
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#303030;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#777;
    font-size:20px;
    transition:color linear 0.15s;
    }
 
.toggle-nav:hover, .toggle-nav.active {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#66a992;
    }





}
    



article {
    clear: both;
    font-family: open sans;
    font-size: 1em;
}

article p {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;

}

footer {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.arrow {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Yoo Free Recharge App That gives talktime for trying out cool appps">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" maximum-scale=2.0">
        <title>Yoo Get Free Recharge</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>

        
        
        <!-- header start from here-->
    <header>
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul class="active">
            <li class=logo>
            <a href="http://freers250.com"><img class=yoologo  src="yoosmall.png" title="Yoo Get Free Recharge"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="mainmenu">
            <a href="http://getfr.free250rs.com" title="Home">HOME</a>    
            </li>
            <li class="mainmenu">
            <a href="http://yoo.com/advertise" title="Advertise">ADVERTISE</a>
            </li>   
            <li id="mainmenu" class="sub-menu">
                <a href="http://theyoo.com/whoweare" title="Who we are">WHO WE ARE<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="mainmenu">
                <a href="http://theyoo.com/pricing" title="pricing">PRICING</a>
            </li>
            <li class="mainmenu">
                <a href="http://theyoo.com/contact" title="Who we are">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
            </ul>

            <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776</a>
    </nav>
</header>



    
        

        <article>
        
        <p>Yoo Free Recharge App - Yoo is an app that gives free recharge/talktime for trying out new and cool apps you can also refer your friends and get money for that too you can get upto 125Rs. Per Friend <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freerechargeapp.free250rs.free_recharge_app" title="Yoo Free Recharge App" target="_blank"> Download Now</a></p>
        
        </article>

        
        <footer>        
        <div style="font-family:'open sans';" > &copy; Yoo Infotech. All right reserved. </div>
        </footer>
        

        
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is opening for me in the snippet.

Comment: working fine for me in chrome, firefox and safari

Comment: Works for me as well

Comment: See fiddle, menu is working for me too https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cfckvvzw/15/

Comment: Try CTRL+F5 to refreshh the browser.

Comment: @Adam i did that too many times

Comment: @Praveen Yes it's working here but as you can see the menu is opening upwards not downwards it's supposed to open like this http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/responsive-menu/

Comment: @Dorvalla why it's not working on my website

Comment: see this https://gyazo.com/43588636d7193bb4f38e2bbd332f9808 it's not working on my website

Comment: I'm not sure if this is part of the problem but keep in mind your have a 20 px gap in your case styling your max screen width on mobile is 980 but your normal screen doesn't pick it up until 1000 so technically 19 pixel gap I guess.

Comment: it's working here but not in my website strange

Comment: Ayaz, some stuff usually gets saved by your browser to save time on loading your page. Clear the cache and try again. Btw it's working fine on my tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPWforRw_cc) and made my responsive header menu

Here it is [image]

Answer (score 0):

You left this out of your css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
....
.menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120%;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #303030;
}
...
}
```

Comment: @AyazAlam yesterday when I tested your code snippet it wasn't there and the menu opened above the nav icon button. Today it is there and it is working correctly, opening below the nav icon button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some framework like bootstrap or material design

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section